# Ledmac - suppressing page numbers in a series of endnotes

Tags: endnotes, ledmac

I am using [`ledmac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ledmac) to prepare an edition with the variant reading appearing as a series of endnotes keyed to line numbers. Could you tell me how to suppress all the page numbers in this (one) series of endnotes. Most grateful for any help!

Comment: Thanks, Maieul. I'm afraid that my question regarding endnotes in Ledmac was unclear. It is actually the PAGE NUMBERS that I am trying to supress.

Comment: strange idea ...

Answer (score 3):

The printing of line number in endnote is defined by the TeX macro `\printendlines`.

A easy way to disable this printing is to redefine the function, with an empty macro :

`\def\printendlines#1|#2|#3|#4|#5|#6|#7|{}`

Comment: And I will add an option in eledmac (which is the successor of ledmac, more customizable) to disable itin an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

So, if the question is to suppress the page number, the solution is a little differents.

The page number is printed with `\newcommand*{\printnpnum}[1]{p.#1) }`.

So you just have to do `\renewcommand*{\printnpnum}[1]{}`